# Vagrant up not startedcode E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, hyper-v

I'm using W10 and I had a problem with Vagrant-suddenly I cannot do vagrant up. I received error:

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: `["startvm", "e11dfd77-f4e8-4125-8169-d81f7dc44e55", "--type", "headless"]`
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Interface ('VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3') is not a Host-Only Adapter interface (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole"

used to work fine until yesterday. I had a Windows update as well yesterday, but after that update vagrant works well.

What i tried:

- checked Hyper-V platform - is disabled.
- reinstalled VM Box, Vagrant but nothing helped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's an old post but this [link](https://vocon-it.com/2017/09/30/resolving-the-virtualbox-code-e_fail-problem-caused-by-hyper-v/) worked for me.

Open CMD as administrator and run:

```
bcdedit /copy "{current}" /d "Hyper-V" 
bcdedit /set "{current}" hypervisorlaunchtype off
bcdedit /set "{current}" description "non Hyper-V"
```

Comment: That link has an incorrect command (from what I can tell). My Win 10 system didn't like the top  level answer. Consider removing that link to prevent confusion for others down the road maybe. Thanks for sharing your insights though. They helped greatly.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone getting this more recently where the stderr does not mention `VT-x`, but instead is something like this:

```
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Call to NEMR0InitVMPart2 failed: VERR_NEM_INIT_FAILED (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)
```

I finally found that it was a virtualbox update that broke it for me; trying to fix NEM in Windows 11 I guess, but breaking it in Windows 10? See discussion [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=104175) on virtualbox's forum.

Basically if you have W10 and upgraded VirtualBox to 6.1.28, you'll want to downgrade to [6.1.26](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_1).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to network setting in VMware and uncheck `Enable Network Adapter` in the adapter 3 setting.

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without downdrading VirtualBox.
Instead, I used the advice [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed1.). In short, here it is:

1. Open the "Turn Windows features on or off" settings (type *optionalfeatures* in the start menu)
2. Untick all the followings:
   Application Guard
   Credential Guard
   Device Guard
    * Guard
   Containers
   Hyper-V
   Virtual Machine Platform
   Windows Hypervisor Platform
   Windows Sandbox
   Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
3. Restart twice.

Answer (score 0):

As windows updates were installed few days ago and i realize that i have an outdated version of VirtualBox, upgrading was enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox 6.1.34 fixed the issue in my Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened after installing Google Play Games for PC which turned on the Windows Hypervisor Platform.

I turned it of in the "Turn Windows features on or off" tool, and it was back up running.

Maybe there is a way to make both things work at the same time (Play Games and Vagrant) but i didn't have time to investigate.